# ACTION SCRIPT 3.0 IF-ELSE IF-ELSE - Always go to ELSE- ignoring the IFs and Else IFs

Tags: actionscript-3

I need a help for this simple IF ELSE coding. Action Script 3.0

First Page : a text field of "Input your name here" (Instance name "nameField"), so user can input his/her name. Pressing a button to go to next page.
Second Page : THERE IS "IF ELSE" statement, if the name is "Ace" then the Result will show "You are number one", and the other names will go to "You are unknown".

PROBLEM : Whatever name I input, it always goes to "You are unknown". I have checked with the TRACE. But still goes to "You are unknown" . STRANGE.

First Page Code:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
stop ();
var myName: String = nameField.text
ClickBtn. addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, movingtopagetwo);
function movingtopagetwo (event:MouseEvent):void
{
   myName = nameField.text;
   gotoAndPlay ("PageTwo");
}
```

---

Second Page Code:

```
trace ("Input just now = "+myName);

if (myName == "Ace") {
    ResultText.text =("You are number one, "+ myName)
} else if (myName == "Blue") {
    ResultText.text =("You color my life, "+ myName);
} else if (myName == "Crow") {
    ResultText.text =("You are free, "+ myName);
} else {
    ResultText.text =("You are unknown, "+ myName);
}
```

[Fla Files Link - ANIMATE/ FLASH](https://ufile.io/jp53t)

Comment: I don't know actionScript, but in the some languages, you cannot compare strings with `==`. (Java has `equals` operator for example)

Comment: @NatNgs Operator == is correct for non-strict (strict comparison === also take exact value types into account) comparison of 2 values.

Comment: @David, so, the exact output of your **trace** statement? I don't see the problem with your code besides the point where you assign **myName** value inside the event handler.

Comment: try with switch / case

Answer (score 1):

NatNgs, Organis, thanks for your help.

Joe, The uses of "IF ELSE" and "CASE" is the same, I've tried "CASE" you have given, and adding semicolon, and it's not solving the problem, STILL THE SAME ERROR.

LUCKILY, I FIND THE SOLUTION THIS MORNING, the nameField (Input text area) should be **Single Line**. While previously the **default** set (Container and Flow's behaviour) is as a **MULTI LINE.**

So this is the solution problem. Thank you guys, please help me next time too.
Together we are developing.

Comment: Then the actual reason is that you must have pre-set some extra characters to the InputText (row changes, spaces?). Instead of forcing user to replace the placeholder text, empty the field on mouse click.

Answer (score 0):

`Actionscript` is case sensitive, are you sure you have written the correct name?

It's possible compare two strings with `==` operator.

A hint: Please use semicolon (`;`) at the end of your statement.

You have missed here: `var myName: String = nameField.text`

and you have missed here: `ResultText.text =("You are number one, "+ myName)`

Your compile goes OK but this can create issue about interpretation of code.

So you can try this:

```
switch(myName) {
    case "Ace": {
        ResultText.text = ("You are number one, "+ myName);
        break;
    }
    case "Blue": {
        ResultText.text = ("You color my life, "+ myName);
        break;
    }
    case "Crow": {
        ResultText.text = ("You are free, "+ myName);
        break;
    }
    default: {
        ResultText.text = ("You are unknown, "+ myName);
    }
}
```